# Multiple index suggestions with same columns

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sqlperformance

I have a table that gets thousands of select queries per hour. SQL server is suggesting that I create four indexes, with 99 % improvement estimate for each:

- [TableName] ([Code Qualifier]) **(Query 3)**
- [TableName] ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Line No_]) **(Query 1)**
- [TableName] ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Status])
- [TableName] ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Status], [Line No_]) **(Query 2)**

Types are as follows:

- [Code Qualifier] `nvarchar(20)`
- [Line Code] `nvarchar(20)`
- [Status] `tinyint`
- [Line No_] `int`

The table is not updated as frequently, select queries seem to outnumber updates/inserts about 1000 to 1. The question is then, should I create all indexes or will one index serve to improve all queries? And if I would want to add one at a time, and check performance after each, in which order should I add them, and should they be added separately or in some combinations? And if the question cannot be answered, is there anything I could do to find out, besides trial and error, which is not an option because I can't modify these myself.

EDIT (queries linked to indexes suggested):

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT  TOP (1) 
    * --enumerated, but still all columns selected
FROM
    "TableName" WITH(UPDLOCK)  
WHERE 
    ("Line Code"=@0 AND "Code Qualifier"=@1 AND "Line No_"=@2)
ORDER BY 
    "Message Batch Number" ASC,
    "Message Line Number" ASC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT 
    * --enumerated, but still all columns selected
FROM 
    "TableName" WITH(UPDLOCK)
WHERE 
    ("Line Code"=@0 AND "Code Qualifier"=@1 AND "Status"=@2 AND "Line No_"=@3) 
ORDER BY 
    "Message Batch Number" ASC,
    "Message Line Number" ASC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN, FAST 50)
```

**Query 3:**

```
UPDATE 
    "TableName" 
SET 
    "Status"=@0 
WHERE ("Code Qualifier"=@1)
```

So, one of the was actually an update. This is done also many times per hour, but not as frequently as the selects. I couldn't find one of these queries immediately, but hopefully these will do.

**EDIT 2 (Existing indexes):**
So these are already in place, but not used in hardly any queries:

- [Message Batch Number] (int), [Message Line Number] (int) (Clustered)
- [Status], [Message Batch Number], [Message Line Number]
- [Control Reference] (nvarchar(30), [Message Batch Number], [Message Line Number]

Comment: Do not create all the indexes. Please show the `select` queries, so we can decide which is best. There are a number of simple rules of thumb, see eg https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/index-key-column-order-and-supporting-sorts/

Comment: Read this [dba thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300688/created-an-index-for-a-table-adding-just-one-more-column-and-sql-still-suggest) - the missing index feature is not that good.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I added some queries.

Comment: Nothing is free. There is a cost for every index. You need to weigh the costs of any index against the benefit. If you are not attempting to solve any problem, then just ignore the tuning suggestions. So far, it does not appear you are problem solving, but there are no generic answers. You test to see if any index change is "good".

Comment: I know there is a cost, this is why I'm asking. The problem is that these queries are showing every day in my top resource consumers. If I could actually cut their execution times by 99 %, that would mean almost 2 hours of processing time saved each day. If I could change freely, I would have, but alas these are maintained from our ERP development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to test this by replicating our production database and running these queries in a loop with and without different indexes. Surprisingly, it seemed that adding a nonclustered index only on `Code Qualifier` dropped execution times to practically zero on all queries with a few dozen iterations. So in answer to my own question, a single index for a single column seems quite sufficient for practical purposes.

Comment: After adding this to production, the results were astounding. All three queries improved by a factor of 1.000-15.000 with this single-column index. During the week the total duration was over 7 hours and this is now mere seconds, with average duration dropping from 40-1000 ms to 0,07 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the queries in isolation, you ideally need the following indexes:

**Query 1**

```sql
CLUSTERED INDEX ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Line No_],
  [Message Batch Number], [Message Line Number])
-- first three columns in any order
```

**Query 2**

```sql
CLUSTERED INDEX ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Line No_], Status,
  [Message Batch Number], [Message Line Number])
-- first four columns in any order
```

The ordering of those first columns should be most selective first.

You can combine the first two indexes, by putting removing `Status`. The downside is that it cannot be seeked, but since it is a clustered index that will not matter as much. If you want a non-clustered index then *all* other selected columns should be in the `INCLUDE`.

**So the final indexing needed is:**

```sql
CLUSTERED INDEX ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Line No_],
  [Message Batch Number], [Message Line Number])
-- first three columns in any order

-- you can change it to NONCLUSTERED by using INCLUDE
NONCLUSTERED INDEX ([Line Code], [Code Qualifier], [Line No_],
  [Message Batch Number], [Message Line Number])
  INCLUDE (Status, anyOtherColumnsHere)
```

**For Query 3** you just need,

```sql
NONCLUSTERED INDEX ([Code Qualifier]) INCLUDE (Status)
```

If you are using an ORM such as Linq2SQL (which it would seem, given the parameter names), ensure that the correct variable data types and lengths are being passed in, otherwise the indexes won't be used

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the Message Batch and Line numbers constitute the primary key, so they will have clustered index and not likely to be changed, so the rest have to be nonclustered, or...? These queries are generated  by the ERP system (Nav), and the indexes are also created there, so I guess they will be used if they just get appropriate queries. Does this information change your answer?

Comment: If all columns are selected then all those extra columns should be in the `INCLUDE`. of a non-clustered index. This is why it's better for it to be clustered, because then all the columns are included anyway. Note that the primary key does not have to be clustered, it could be non-clustered